# Rails: Don't save date if it wasn't changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a class with a date. If the user doesn't change it in the view, Rails saves today's date (the default values in the drop downs). I would like it to be saved as a null value instead. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:include_blank` in your `date_select` helper.  Reference:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M002264

Comment: No problem.  Everybody needs to start somewhere - don't be so hard on yourself.